# SSH Connection loss when roaming to an AP with a different OUI

Tags: ssh, wifi, wpa

I have major issues with a device (Ubuntu 20.04 installed) in a warehouse with multiple access points. I am frequently losing the SSH connection. Investigating the matter, I found out that I lose connection whenever the device roams to a different AP (same SSID). Digging deeper, I found out that the SSH connection is only killed when the device roams to an AP with a different OUI (lets say YY:YY:YY indicating a different AP Manufacturer or AP Model). When I reconnect to the device, I see that it is connected to the AP with OUI YY:YY:YY.

I compared the roaming logs (journalctl -fu wpa_supplicant@wlan0.service) when roaming to a different AP model with the logs when roaming to the same AP model. Besides the BSSIDs, they are identical.

We use a simple WPA2 PSK (no fancy 802.11r or anything). I always thought that roaming happens on the WiFi clients.

Are you aware of anything that could cause such a behavior? Could it be a misconfiguration of the wpa_supplicant? Could it be a misconfiguration of the APs?